# Is there a column-as-record representation of data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, knitr

`data.frame` is a list of vectors which is presented in row-as-record form. However, in some cases, it is more screen-friendly to show data in column-as-record form. For example,

```
> data.frame(date=c("2014-10-01", "2014-10-02", "2014-10-03"), x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,3,4), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
        date x y
1 2014-10-01 1 2
2 2014-10-02 2 3
3 2014-10-03 3 4
```

This representation is friendly for long data with many records. If one wants to put this data into a table, say, by `knitr::kable()` and knit the markdown document to a html document, then the table is too wide for viewers. A visually better way to present this data frame is to transpose it like

```
date 2014-10-01 2014-10-02 2014-10-03
x    1          2          3         
y    2          3          4
```

This can be partially achieved by `t()` but the data frame will be coerced to character matrix, which is undesired in this case.

Is there an existing implementation to easily present a data frame in column-as-record form without turning it into a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools available to help "reshape" your data, and this would be an example of where you should use one of them. For instance, with "reshape2", you can do the following:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(dat, measure.vars = c("x", "y")), 
      variable ~ date, value.var = "value")
#   variable 2014-10-01 2014-10-02 2014-10-03
# 1        x          1          2          3
# 2        y          2          3          4
```

Similarly, with "dplyr" and "tidyr", you can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  gather(Date, value, x, y) %>% 
  spread(date, value)
#   Date 2014-10-01 2014-10-02 2014-10-03
# 1    x          1          2          3
# 2    y          2          3          4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> ddf = data.frame(date=c("2014-10-01", "2014-10-02", "2014-10-03"), x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,3,4), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
> 
> data.frame(t(ddf))
             X1         X2         X3
date 2014-10-01 2014-10-02 2014-10-03
x             1          2          3
y             2          3          4
>
```

For maintaining structure better:

```
tddf = data.frame(t(ddf))
names(tddf) = unlist(tddf[1,])
tddf = tddf [-1,]
tddf = data.frame(sapply(tddf, as.numeric))
rownames(tddf) = c('x','y')
tddf
  X2014.10.01 X2014.10.02 X2014.10.03
x           1           1           2
y           2           3           3

str(tddf)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X2014.10.01: num  1 2
 $ X2014.10.02: num  1 3
 $ X2014.10.03: num  2 3
```

Comment: Thanks! but this is only useful for presentation purpose and does not work for use purpose, I mean, the solution should preserve the data structure and classes of columns, this solution will coerce the data to all character or factor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#input data
df <- data.frame(date=c("2014-10-01", "2014-10-02", "2014-10-03"),
                 x = c(1,2,3),
                 y = c(2,3,4))

#transform
df1 <- data.frame(t(df[,c(2,3)]))
colnames(df1) <- df$date

#output
df1
#   2014-10-01 2014-10-02 2014-10-03
# x          1          2          3
# y          2          3          4
```